# What is the best IDE for developing in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, servlets

Recently I've been doing a bunch of work developing servlets for deployment in Tomcat 5.5.  My current IDE is Eclipse Ganymede with WTP.  I've been very unhappy with the Tomcat integration, as the configuration is constantly breaking and needing tweaking.

I was wondering if anyone could recommend another IDE that handles this integration better.  I am particularly interested in what people think of IntelliJ's support for Tomcat.

Note I am also using Maven 2, and it's pretty essential to have Maven support as well.

Comment: I don't know why people use IDE to begin with. I use only command line with docker. I am at the beginning of learning Tomcat and currently my use case only revolves around HTML forms and basic HTML, CSS, Java tricks like cookie, page count, java logic etc. Here is my repo to get started: https://github.com/bishwashere/tomcat-docker

Answer (score 5):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) has tomcat integration. By that I mean you can start and stop tomcat, deploy, profile and debug your app running in tomcat from the IDE.

[Best Practices for Apache Maven in NetBeans 6.x](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices)

Answer (score 4):

Netbeans all the way.

The integration with tomcat is fantastic, it even allows you to create project and automatically deploy and update on the fly without have to write any sort of build scripts deployment descriptors etc. It really is that easy :-)

http://www.netbeans.org

Comment: Although Eclipse WTP lets you basically do the same thing pretty much. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't using a debugger for JSPs, any IDE (I use Eclipse) works with any J2EE server using remote debugging.  Add this to your startup script for Tomcat:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5001,server=y,suspend=n
```

And then set up a remote debugging profile in your IDE using the port you specified (in this case, 5001).

This configuration never breaks and works for any Java app.  Just run your application as you always do, and attach your debugger whenever you want.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA is *the* IDE for you, having both excellent Tomcat and Maven integration.

Answer (score 3):

I've used MyEclipse, the SysDeo plugin for Eclipse, and WTP.  Of the three, when WTP works, it kicks the pants off the others.  *Most* maven projects will just import and just run.

Unfortuantely sometimes WTP doesnt seem to work, and you're basically SOL.  Our current project has a rather complex maven configuration and I've not yet

- gotten it to work.
- reduced the problem to a small test case to bug-submit.

I highly recommend WTP, particularly if you're already an Eclipse user.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question but, instead of changing the IDE, maybe consider changing the container (and maybe forget the WTP). **I warmly suggest to try Jetty**, especially if you are already using Maven. With a few lines of configuration, you'll be able to run `mvn jetty:run` on your project and Jetty will start, deploy and [scan files](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Which+files+are+scanned+by+the+Jetty+Maven+Plugin) for changes to redeploy the webapp if necessary. Isn't this nice ?

So **I don't use the WTP** but the [maven jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) as it provides useful features to me: simplicity (usage and configuration), short round trip cycles (start and deploy), files scanner, etc and of course integration with maven. Inside Eclipse, I use externals tools to stop and start Jetty by calling the maven plugin. For debugging, I use remote debug options when launching Jetty and connect a remote debugger on demand as explained in [Debugging with the Maven Jetty Plugin in Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+with+the+Maven+Jetty+Plugin+inside+Eclipse).

This way, I can do all I want from Eclipse and/or maven and I'm happier than with the WTP and any other lightweight container.

Answer (score 0):

I use the sysdeo plugin for eclipse and like it quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug JSPs very nicely with IntelliJ running on Tomcat, Jetty, WebLogic, or any other Java EE container.  Far and away the best IDE.

Comment: How do you run multiple applications on one tomcat easily with IntelliJ? In Netbeans you simply click build and run and it will deploy. And you can rightclick undeploy on one application. I know I can have a tomcat per module or have different applications use different ports, but I haven't found out how I can reload one module after a code change without having to restart the tomcat and other modules too (without JRebel).

Comment: You deploy multiple WARs, of course.  If you wanted to debug each one simultaneously you'd have to open each project, deploy on individual Tomcats running on different ports.  I am running four different instances of JBOSS on my machine right now using IntelliJ.

Comment: Okay then I'll go with different ports. Still a shame that it can't do it like Netbeans does modules on one tomcat with the same port. (I prefer IntelliJ for coding, but the tomcat integration in Netbeans is pretty good)

Comment: Use Netbeans if you must.  I think it's an inferior product.  I don't find the restart to be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij has great Tomcat and Maven support. If you can afford to spend a few bucks, it's definitely worth the money. You can get a 30 day free trial of Intellij. Give it a shot and you won't look back.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll like [MyEclipse IDE](http://www.myeclipseide.com/). Ain't free but IMHO it's worth it.

Comment: Why should someone, both in 2009 or now, pay like $37/year when Eclipse IDE from the actual Eclipse foundation exists and it's free and open source? What does this fork offers to justify its price? All assuming Intellij IDEA doesn't suite your needs or preferences and you prefer the Eclipse base